# what does 무리수을 뛌어 and 무리수를 너가 이제 제대로 두는구나 mean?

Tags: vocabulary

what does 무리수을 뛌어 mean?
What is the meaning of the sentence 무리수를 너가 이제 제대로 두는구나 ?

Answer (score 5):

무리수(無理手, **do not confuse with 無理數 which means irrational number**.) was a term of Go originally. It meant an overreaching move that may cause serious threat in future. Now it became a conversational word. If someone is overdoing oneself, others can say "저 사람은 무리수를 두었다"

Comment: aha... so it's a 'Go' term that has become a more generally-used idiom?

Comment: @topo morto / Exactly. Even many native Korean speakers don't know the correct origin of this word.

Answer (score 4):

무리수을 뛌어 is a misspelling of 무리수를 뒀어.

As well as its mathematical meaning which you will find in a dictionary, 무리수 means to 'overdo' or 'overreach' - to be too ambitious. 무리 하다 is a verb form meaning to go too far.

두다 means to put down or set down. So 무리수을 뒀어 means that something was 'put down too ambitiously'. It could apply to an over-ambitious move in a board game, for example.

Answer (score 0):

**무리수 : way which is not in his control**.

무리수를 너가 이제 제대로 두는구나

Now, you act with your full power a thing, which is not near to your ability.

**제대로 : suitable degree, fitting to regulation**.

제대로 해라. Do it under a good condition.

제대로 되는 일이 없다. There is nothing, which is done suitably.

http://dic.daum.net/word/view.do?wordid=kkw000229897&supid=kku000292785